# how call output$ elements from shiny in Markdown

Tags: r, shiny, output, r-markdown

i'm trying to create a report based on my shiny App, currently i have done a markdown with some inputs and reactive values, but i'm unable to call output$ elements fro my shiny.
My question is, how can i add those "output" elements into my rmarkdown, is there any specific way to call into a Markdown ?

This is my code, the last line is not working:

````
---
output: html_document
# &nbsp; for espace
# <br /> or <p>&nbsp;</p> for line blank
---
  
  
  
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(stringr)
library(knitr)
library(jsonlite)
library(gtools)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(stringr)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(shiny)
library(fitdistrplus)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(miceadds)
library(plotly)
library(formattable)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(clipr)
library(readxl)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(httr)
library(tidyr)
library(plyr)
library(leaflet)
library(scales)
library(highcharter)
library(gridExtra)
library(gt)
library(data.table)
library(janitor)
library(purrr)

# <span style="color:#702080">  Coverage Breadth Analysis - D&O Liability   </span>

>## <span style="color:#702080">  Section 1: `r score1()` / 174   </span>   
  
<span style="color:#c110a0;text-align:center">Policy Check </span> | <span style="color:#c110a0;text-align:center">Provision</span> | <span style="color:#c110a0;text-align:center">Comment/Recommendation</span> | <span style="color:#c110a0;text-align:center">Weight</span>     
:--------- | :-------------------: | :-----------------: | ---:
  
`r if(input$check11 %in% input$check_report_){ fluidRow(style = "border-top: 1px solid; border-color: #A9A9A9; padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;",column(2, input$check11, style =  align_center), column(4, prov11_prev(), style =  align_justify ), column(5,  input$text_c_11), column(1,  weight11(), style =  align_center) )} else{}`


>## <span style="color:#702080">  Heat Map   </span>

`r output$heatmap_hc `
````

Thanks !!

Comment: One cannot "call" `output$` objects. If you need the data that goes into rendering an output, then you likely want a two-step approach: (a) create reactive data, as in `somedat <- reactive({...})`; then (b) have the output rely *solely* on it, as in `output$plot <- renderTable({somedat()})`. It's difficult to say a lot more since this is not a working example, but I hope this is enough of a clue to get you started.

Comment: Your code has no `input`s defined, not much for HTML layout, no `shiny` code, and only tries to reference `output$heatmap_hc` with no definition of it. I'm inferring that there is much more to your code than you are showing it. Are you able to provide a MWE? (Perhaps one that does not rely on 33 packages.)